# Leerzeichen und Strich in »Zusammenhang Sex – Liebe«

Tags: punctuation, writing

Angenommen, man will "Zusammenhang zwischen Sex und Liebe" zu drei Wörtern abkürzen: "Zusammenhang", "Sex" und "Liebe", mit irgendeinem Strich zwischen "Sex" und "Liebe". Welche Zeichensetzung ist korrekt?

1. Zusammenhang Sex-Liebe
2. Zusammenhang Sex - Liebe
3. Zusammenhang Sex–Liebe
4. Zusammenhang Sex – Liebe
5. Zusammenhang Sex—Liebe
6. Zusammenhang Sex — Liebe

?

Die Frage ist ernst: ich editiere einen Text und stehe gerade total auf dem Schlauch.

Answer (score 5):

### Gedankenstrich

In diesem Fall ist nur der Gedankenstrich richtig *(Halbgeviertstrich,* “n-dash”, –). Der gewöhnliche Bindestrich würde eine Begriffskopplung bezeichnen *(Sex-Liebe* im Sinn von ‘Sexliebe’), und der Geviertstrich (“m-dash”, —) wird in der deutschen Typographie nicht verwendet.

Die interessante Frage ist: Braucht es Leerzeichen oder nicht?

Der Duden und andere typografische Empfehlungen unterscheiden zwei verschiedene Fälle:

1. Gedankenstrich ohne Leerzeichen als Streckenstrich *(Hamburg–Berlin)* oder als Ersatz von «bis» bei Zahlen *(14–16 Uhr, 1991–94, 10–12 Mark).*
2. Gedankenstrich mit Leerzeichen als Abtrennung – gewissermassen eine Alternative zu Kommas oder Klammern – oder als Ersatz von «gegen» (oder «bis») zwischen Wörtern *(Schalke 04 – Eintracht Frankfurt).*

Beim genannten Ausdruck geht es nicht um eine Abtrennung (Fall 2), sondern um einen Zusammenhang. Man sollte also gewissermassen wie bei einem Streckenstrich (Fall 1) **kein Leerzeichen** verwenden: *Zusammenhang Sex–Liebe.*

Besonders augenfällig wird dies, wenn man den Ausdruck nicht isoliert betrachtet, sondern in einem Satz. Nur ohne Leerzeichen lässt sich ein solcher Satz richtig lesen:

> Der Zusammenhang Sex–Liebe ist ganz etwas anders.

Wenn ich hingegen die Leerzeichen setze, dann wird der Satz falsch gelesen:

> *Der Zusammenhang Sex – Liebe ist ganz etwas anderes.

Dies liest sich wie: «Der Zusammenhang Sex, Liebe ist ganz etwas anderes, …».

### Schrägstrich

Wie Ĵоħп Đое bereits gesagt hat, wäre hier wohl ein Schrägstrich vorzuziehen, denn gem. [§106](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf#page=101) kennzeichnet der Schrägstrich: «dass  Wörter  (Namen,  Abkürzungen), Zahlen oder dergleichen zusammengehören.»

Answer (score 4):

Auf jeden Fall muss ein Leerzeichen vor und nach dem Strich gesetzt werden. Ohne Leerzeichen wäre es ein einzelnes Wort, das man auch ohne Strich schreiben könnte: Sexliebe.

> Auto-Bahn = Autobahn
>   Donau-Dampfschiff = Donaudampfschiff
>   Sex-Liebe = Sexliebe

Bleibt die Frage, welcher Strich zu verwenden ist. In Frage kommen:

- **Viertelgeviertstrich (‐)**
  Der Viertelgeviertstrich wird als Bindestrich (*Donau-Dampfschiff*) und als Ergänzungsstrich verwendet (*Haupt- und Nebensilben; Bundesstraßen und -bahnen*). Auch in Datumsangaben findet man diesen Strich: 2018-03-30. Aber nichts davon trifft hier zu, daher ist dieser Strich hier die falsche Wahl.
- **Halbgeviertstrich (–)**
  Neben vielen anderen Verwendungszwecken wird er auch als Gegenstrich verwendet: *»Das Spiel Rapid – Sturm endete unentschieden.«* Ebenso bei Gegenüberstellungen: *»einerseits – andererseits«*.

Richtig ist also der Halbgeviertstrich (–) mit umgebenden Leerzeichen:

> Zusammenhang Sex – Liebe

Comment: Wenn ich den Fragesteller richtig verstanden habe, möchte er seinen Satzteil zu »Zusammenhang zwischen Sex und Liebe« abkürzen. Dafür gibt Wikipedia noch einen Spezialfall an und bezieht sich [hierauf](https://www.zeichen-setzen.ch/assets/zb_14-3_halbgeviertstrich.pdf): Wenn der Halbgeviertstrich im Sinn von »zwischen … und« eingesetzt wird, so wird er ohne Leerzeichen gesetzt.

Comment: Wenn es jetzt aber darum geht, Empfehlungen auszusprechen, würde ich den Satz gar nicht abkürzen, um Verwechselungen mit dem Bindestrich zu vermeiden. Oder, wie es Pollitzer vorgeschlagen hat, als »Sex/Liebe-Zusammenhang« umschreiben.

Answer (score 1):

Mein erster Gedanke war der Schrägstrich: `Zusammenhang Sex/Liebe`.

Comment: Mit dem Bindestrich wäre Sex-Liebe ein Wort, gleichbedeutend mit Sexliebe. Das ist aber nicht gemeint

Comment: Kannst Du das begründen? Warum Schrägstrich und nichts anderes? Was bedeutet der Schrägstrich?

Comment: Dividiert. Du dividierst Sex durch Liebe und erhältst die Menge Sex auf eine Liebeseinheit. In SI wird es üblicherweise mit S/L abgekürzt ;-).

Answer (score 1):

Beim Verketten von Wörtern wird das (ich nenne es mal) Minuszeichen¹ verwendet.

> Das In-den-Wald-Gehen belebt die Seele.

Der Schrägstrich kennzeichnet Verschiedenartiges. Für deinen Fall würde ich so etwas wie

> - der Sex/Liebe-Zusammenhang
> - die Sex/Liebe-Relation
> - das Sex/Liebe-Problem

empfehlen.

»Der Zusammenhang Sex/Liebe« klingt linkisch und bleibt hinter »der Zusammenhang von Sex und Liebe« zurück.

---

¹<sub>Genaueres geht aus den Kommentaren hervor.</sub>

Comment: Nein, beim Koppeln wird der Viertelgeviertstrich, und nicht das Minuszeichen, verwendet – es sei denn, man schreibt auf einer Schreibmaschine. Abgesehen davon, geht es bei der Frage gar nicht um Kopplung, sondern um die Gegenüberstellung von Wörtern. Einzig richtig ist hier also ein Halbgeviertstrich.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Bei [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viertelgeviertstrich) heißt es: _»... auf der Computer-Tastatur wird mit der „Bindestrich-Taste“ ein Bindestrich-Minus erzeugt«_, wobei das Bindestrich-Minus etwas breiter sein soll als der Viertelgeviertstrich.

Comment: *wobei das Bindestrich-Minus etwas breiter sein soll als der Viertelgeviertstrich* – Wo genau steht das da? Und selbst wenn es da stünde, hätte es wenig mit der Realität zu tun und ist keiner Schrift, die ich kenne der Fall. So oder so, ist das immer noch etwas anderes als das Minuszeichen.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Das steht in dem Satz, der dem zitierten vorausgeht. – Wenn ich am Computer ein Minus oder einen Bindestrich tippen will, habe ich dafür nur ein mögliches Zeichen, das ich für beide Fälle verwenden muss.

Comment: @Pollitzer: *Das steht in dem Satz, der dem zitierten vorausgeht.* – …, welcher von Schreibmaschinen spricht. — *Wenn ich am Computer ein Minus oder einen Bindestrich tippen will, habe ich dafür nur ein mögliches Zeichen, das ich für beide Fälle verwenden muss.* – Das ist falsch. Hier sind Bindestrich-Minus, Bindestrich, und Minus (in dieser Reihenfolge): - ‐ −. (Nebenbei hast Du es selbst in obigem Kommentar geschafft, einen Halbgeviertstrich zu verwenden.)

Comment: WYSIWYG-Textverarbeitungsprogramme wie Word und Libreoffice versuchen, einem diese Feinheiten abzunehmen, manchmal geht es aber schief. Wer bessere Kontrolle über typografische Details möchte, sollte sich ein vernünftiges Nachschlagewerk besorgen („Detailtypografie“ von Friedrich Forssman ist die Königsklasse), in LaTeX setzen und auf ein vernünftiges Tastaturlayout, z. B. Neo, wechseln.

Comment: Wegen der möglichen Verwechslungsgefahr mit dem Bindestrich zur Kopplung würde ich auch lieber einen Schrägstrich nehmen. Die Wahl (und Bedeutungsunterschiede) der verschiedenen Formen des Bindestrichs ist zu unbekannt und wird zu häufig falsch gemacht, als dass ich mich auf den Unterschied zwischen einem Viertel- und Halbgeviertstrich verlassen würde, um die Bedeutung zu hinterlegen. Und die zwei Begriffe gekoppelt würden was volkommen anderes bedeuten, als der OP ausdrücken will.

Comment: Das Minuszeichen hat beim Verketten von Wörtern überhaupt nichts zu suchen. Es wird ausschließlich als mathematischer Operator verwendet (z.B. mit Zahlen: *»5 - 3 = 2«* oder auch mit Variablen *»a - b = c«*). Es macht schlichtweg keinen Sinn, ein Minus zwischen Wörter zu setzen, wenn man damit nicht rechnen will. Das Minus sieht zwar fast gleich aus wie ein Viertelgeviertstrich (Divis), und wird mit ihm daher oft verwechselt, ist aber ein anderes Zeichen (z.B. in Unicode: Minus = U+2212; Divis = U+2010). (wird fortgesetzt)

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Bei der Konstruktion von Schreibmaschinen, und später bei der Einführung des ASCII-Zeichensatzes, bestand die Notwendigkeit, mit möglichst wenigen Tasten bzw. Bytecodes auszukommen. Daher wurden damals die Zeichen *Minus* und *Bindestrich* mit derselben Taste getippt bzw. mit dem selben Code codiert. Das macht diese Zeichen aber trotzdem nicht gleich. Merke: Wenn du rechnest, verwendest du ein Minuszeichen. Wenn die Wörter verwendest, einen Bindestrich (auch *Viertelgeviertstrich* oder *Divis* genannt) (wird fortgesetzt)

Comment: (Fortsetzung) Das Minus ist etwas länger als der Bindestrich. Daher hat das Mischzeichen *Bindestrich-Minus* eine Länge, die dazwischen liegt. Daher ist das echte Minuszeichen etwas länger als das Bindestrich-Minus, und dieses wiederum etwas länger als der echte Bindestrich.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast:  Auf meiner Tastatur habe ich zwei kurze Querstriche, die beim Tippen vertikal mittig positioniert werden: eins auf dem Nummernblock und eins auf der Taste links neben der rechten Umschalttaste. Beide Zeichen sehen bei mir gleich aus. Welches ich verwende, wenn ich ein Minus oder einen Bindestrich brauche, ist egal, daher habe ich von Minuszeichen gesprochen.

Comment: @Pollitzer: Das sind zwei Tasten für dasselbe Zeichen, nämlich für das Mischwesen Bindestrich-Minus (Unicode U+002D). Das ist weder ein Bindestrich (U+2010) noch ein Minus (U+2212), sondern ein Zwitter aus beidem. Wenn man Bequemlichkeit einer genauen Typografie vorzieht, kann man das Bindestrich-Minus als Ersatz sowohl für das Minus als auch für den Bindestrich verwenden. Aber es ist eben nur ein Ersatz. Und es ist kein Minus, und schon gar nicht setzt man ein Minus zwischen Wörter (außer die Wörter sind mathematische Variablen, mit denen man rechnen will, z.B. in *»Brutto − Netto = Tara«*)